# Setting up VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm brand new to VM's and I have zero clue how set one up. I read through the VirtualBoxes manual and followed the directions to a T, but when I try and start the VM I can't find a start up disk despite having created one in the setup. I've tried all the different settings, I tried saving the disk to my desktop to locate it, I tried saving it into the folder that's holding VirtualBox and still nothing. Can I get some help?

Comment: I'll download virtual box and post a tutorial on how to set it up :) I'm using VMware usually so it should be similar process.

Comment: Did you add the .iso to the cd/dvd images?

Comment: @SkyRamon That be sweet. Drop a link.

Comment: @DrZoo I can check again, but I'm positive that did.

Comment: @Jason check my answer and let me know if it worked for you. Otherwise I'll add some images.

Comment: @SkyRamon I have it up and running right now. That's best step by step I've gotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Virtual Box which can be downloaded [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

1. Click on New and fill in a name. then click on next
2. Then choose the memory size ( I recommend at least 2048 MB ). Click
   on next.
3. At the Hard Disk part click on Create.
4. Then click on VDI and click on next.
5. Storage on physical hard disk just click next

Then when you have that you will see your Win 7 icon don't press start yet. We will now select the file to boot (e.x windows 7.iso file)

1. Go right click on it and choose settings
2. Then click on storage and select the empty cd disk.
3. At the Attributes on the right side click on the micro cd-disk icon.
4. then Choose virtual optic disk.
5. Select your .ISO file of the operating system that you want.
6. and then click on start.

This should start up the virtual machine. And you should be fine. Just keep the default settings for most of the Windows operating systems and you should be fine. Even in the beginning you can select what os you are going to install and it will change the default settings to fit that os.